# Threejs and dropdowns: How to display only selected model?

Tags: javascript, three.js, dropdown, gltf, 3d-model

I'd like to display only selected value (in this case the 3d model) from dropdown option. Only selected one should be visible to the camera. Here is the code part that i'm stuck with:

```
                    const loader = new GLTFLoader().setPath('models/gltf/modeldatabase/');
                for (let i = 0; i < prefabcontainer.length; i++) {

                    let prefabResource = prefabcontainer[i];

                    loader.load(prefabResource, function (gltf) {

                        object = gltf.scene;
                        object.scale.set(5, 5, 5);
                        
                        var select = document.getElementById("selectPrefab");
                        prefabResource = prefabResource.replace(/\..+$/, '');
                        var prefabElement = document.createElement("option");
                        prefabElement.textContent = prefabResource;
                        prefabElement.value = prefabResource;
                        select.appendChild(prefabElement);
                        scene.add(object);
                        render();

                    }, undefined, function (error) {
                        console.error(error);
                    })

            }
```

Prefabcontainer is just a simple js script:

```
let prefabcontainer = [
'shotgun.gltf',
'pistol.gltf'];

export{prefabcontainer};
```

And here is the html part:

```
<div><select id="selectPrefab">
```

I appreciate your help, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Outside the `for` loop, declare an array to hold the loaded objects.  Also create a `DocumentFragment` to hold the `<options>` while you're generating them; this way, you're only making one change to the DOM, once all the `<option>`s have been generated. Also move the declaration of `select` to this scope.

```js
...
+   const select = document.getElementById("selectPrefab");
+   const prefabObjects = [];
+   const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    for (let i = 0; i < prefabcontainer.length; i++) {
         ...
-        var select = document.getElementById("selectPrefab");
...
```

Change the line that sets the `<option>`'s value so that it uses the index, and set the `defaultSelected` property on the first `<option>`.  For this, use the [Option(text, value, defaultSelected) constructor<sup>[MDN]</sup>](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option).

```js
...
-   var prefabElement = document.createElement("option");
-   prefabElement.textContent = prefabResource;
-   prefabElement.value = prefabResource;
-   select.appendChild(prefabElement);
+   const prefabElement = new Option(prefabResource, i, i === 0);
+   fragment.appendChild(prefabElement);
...
```

Declare a function for changing the `visible` property on a Three.js `Object3D` and its children.

```js
function traverseSetVisible(startObject, visible) {
    startObject.traverse(function(obj) {
        if(obj.isObject3D) {
            obj.visible = visible;
        }
    });
}
```

Add the loaded object to the array declared above.  On the second and subsequent objects, set the `visible` property to false.  Wrap the call to `render()` here in a conditional looking for the first object.

```js
...
    fragment.appendChild(prefabElement);
+   prefabObjects.push(object);
+   if (i !== 0) {
+       traverseSetVisible(object, false);
+   }
    scene.add(object);
-   render();
+   if (i === 0) {
+       render();
+   }
...
```

Finally, outside the `for` loop, add the generated `<option>`s fragment to the `<select>`.  Add an event listener to handle selections in the drop-down by toggling the `visible` state of the prefabs.

```js
     } // end of for loop
+    select.appendChild(fragment);
+    select.addEventListener('change', function() {
+         const selectedValue = parseInt(select.Value);
+         for (let i = 0; i < prefabObjects.length; i++) {
+              const visible = i === selectedValue;
+              traverseSetVisible(prefabObjects[i], visible);
+         }
+         render();
+    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I almost got it working. For some reason after this call: `loader.load(prefabResource, function (gltf) {}` the prefabResource lists randomly prefabContainer objects. Outside GLTFloader call the prefablist are listing the object in right order. Can't figure out why is so.

Comment: My guess would be that it's because `loader.load()` is asynchronous; the loads must be finishing out of order and thus invoking the callback out of order.  Try moving any line that doesn't touch `gltf` or `object` out of the callback (note that you'll need to declare a new variable to receive the result of `prefabResource.replace()`).